# Perl WWW::Mechanize encoding issue

Tags: perl, web, mechanize, www-mechanize

I have the following code:

```
my ($url) = "http://example.com"
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get($url);
my $c = $m->content;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $c );

if (my $content = $tree->look_down(_tag => "div", class => "content")) {
    $content = $content->as_text();
}
```

The issue is, when I parse the content, some of the text has a single or double quotes that do  not get parsed correctly. For example `“this”` becomes `â€œthisâ€` .

It is my understanding that this is some `Windows-1252` encoding. How can I fix it?

I tried adding `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';` at the start of the program, it did not help.

I tried adding `$content = utf8::decode($content);` but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$m->decoded_content;
```

instead of

```
$m->content;
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Can't locate object method "decoded_content" via package "WWW::Mechanize" at script.pl line 75.`

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing `WWW::Mechanize::DecodedContent`. Once that was fixed the code worked. But I am still getting the same issue. For another example, I am getting `eâ€¦` instead of `...`

Comment: OK, I had to moduify your answer to: `$m->decoded_content(charset => 'utf8');`

Comment: It sounds like the website you're trying to scrape is not properly reporting the character set it's using.

Comment: Well, I tested it on StackOverflow and it is the same result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279605/qt-open-libqtcore-so-4-o-rdonlyo-cloexec-1-enoent-no-such-file-or-di . For `“..libQtCore.so.4”` I am getting `â€œ..libQtCore.so.4â€`